# Code for Project Euler No 45 not working

Tags: c++

Here is the problem, [Project Euler #45](http://projecteuler.net/problem=45)

And here's the code I wrote for it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

bool ispent (long num){
    long double x = (sqrt(24*num+1) + 1.0)/6.0;
    if (floor(x)==x) return true;
    else return false;
}

bool ishex (long num){
    long double x = (sqrt(8*num+1) + 1.0)/4.0;
    if (floor(x)==x) return true;
    else return false;
}

int main(){
    int i=286;
    while(true){
        long x = (i*(i+1))/2;
        if((ispent(x)) && (ishex(x))){
            cout << x;
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

This gives the output 40755, whereas I require the next number. What could be the possible bug?

Comment: you can't reach the next one number if you leave at the first match you find. (the first match being the number from the example)

Comment: i don't understand. Why would I encounter 40755 when i starts from 286?

Comment: When I run your code, I don't get 40755, because that's what you get when you start at 285.  You're probably not running the executable you think you're running, and are running your old test code instead.

Comment: @Peter what do you get as an answer?

Comment: I got tired of waiting.  But it's running, and definitely not outputting 40755

Comment: So what do u think is the problem?

Comment: Hmm, maybe you're seeing the wraparound, after i increments past the end of 32-bits and back around to 285.  See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that using square roots to check if a number is pentagonal or hexagonal is imprecise, so the test will fail and you will overflow `x`.

To fix this, you can use a type with more precision, like replacing `long` with `unsigned long`, or even `unsigned long long`.

Comment: x can't be 40755 as I am starting from i=286, whereas x=40755 happens when i=285

Comment: Actually, I tested your `ispent` and `ishex` functions against the next number (the correct answer to the problem), and they both return false.

Comment: So probably its an overflow. What should I do to make it right?

Comment: The next number is 1533776805. And my compiler return 1 when i punch in these values in `ishex` and `ispent`.

Comment: I used a g++ compiler on ubuntu. No idea of the version. Anyways, any suggestions to improve my code?

Comment: A better approach would be to realize that all hexagonal numbers are triangular numbers.  Also, checking if a number is hexagonal or pentagonal using square roots isn't great.  It is better if all your computations were integers, like `unsigned long`.  You could dynamically generate the next pentagonal number and hexagonal number (if pentagonal number is smaller, generate next pentagonal number), and do an integer comparison.

Comment: i replace `long` with `unsigned long` and voila! It gave the correct answer in a second! Thanks a lot! Can you edit your answer so that I can vote it up and place the green tick?!

Comment: No problem.  I just made the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You are overflowing the 32-bit representation of x.  If you know the next x is 1533776805, then an intermediate value of 2x is necessary, which at 3e9 overflows a signed integer.  You can *just* fit this in an unsigned int, but I would use a 64-bit integer instead.  `#include <stdint.h>`, and use int64_t for both i and x.  But I agree with the other commenters, there's something suspicious about testing for exact double precision answers

Comment: Or don't bother with `<stdint.h>`, and use `long long`.  (That's what it's there for, after all.)